# Truly change a model attribute silently in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way I can change attributes on a model without ever firing a change event? If you pass `{"silent":true}` right now, the next time an attribute is changed, the silent change event will be triggered. Can I change an attribute safely without the change event ever being triggered?

from change, Backbone 0.9.2:

```
// Silent changes become pending changes.
for (var attr in this._silent) this._pending[attr] = true;

// Silent changes are triggered.
var changes = _.extend({}, options.changes, this._silent);
this._silent = {};
for (var attr in changes) {
    this.trigger('change:' + attr, this, this.get(attr), options);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the cleanest way if you really want to default to silent (but still be able to do silent:false) sets would be to override `set`. This should do it:

```
var SilentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    set: function(attrs, options) {
        options = options || {};
        if (!('silent' in options)) {
            options.silent = true;
        }
        return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attrs, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem of { silent: true } delaying the individual change:attr events is fixed in Backbone 0.9.10.

Answer (score 11):

You can change model attributes directly using `model.attributes['xyz'] = 123`.

Comment: Wow, that truly did it. So simple.

Comment: I've heard a couple of people advising to not touch the `attributes` variable. But it seems to do the job. Is there a real and pragmatic drawback in doing it that way?

Comment: @cherouvim I think the only drawback is exactly what we want - no events.

Comment: Take care if you set another object as an attribute. JSON.stringify() or toJSON() will produce different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
item.set(
        {
           sum: sum
          ,income: income
       },
       {silent: true}
    );
```

since backbone 0.9.10